# php composer autoload class not found error

Tags: php, composer-php, hybridauth

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//Include Composer's autoloader
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

public function test_auth() {       
try{
      $hybridauth = new Hybridauth\Hybridauth($config);

        //Attempt to authenticate users with a provider by name
        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate('Twitter'); 

        //Returns a boolean of whether the user is connected with Twitter
        $isConnected = $adapter->isConnected();

        //Retrieve the user's profile
        $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

        //Inspect profile's public attributes
        var_dump($userProfile);

        //Disconnect the adapter 
        $adapter->disconnect();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'Oops, we ran into an issue! ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

> An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'Hybridauth\Hybridauth\Hybridauth' not found

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\paymatrix_v2\application\controllers\Hauth.php

Line Number: 35

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paymatrix_v2\index.php
Line: 294
Function: require_once

> composer.json file

```
{
"description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
"name": "codeigniter/framework",
"type": "project",
"homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
"license": "MIT",
"support": {
    "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
    "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/codeigniter",
    "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.4",
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^2.1",
    "php-http/curl-client": "^1.6",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.3",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*",
    "pipl/piplapis-php" : "^5.0",
    "hybridauth/hybridauth": "^2.9"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
        "classmap": ["vendor/pipl/piplapis-php/src","vendor/pipl/"]
}
```

}

> autoload.php

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit9da23362304113093d59b5cbcc0e2b35::getLoader();
```

> hybrid auth location

```
vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/
```

Comment: please show your autoload file and the  location where is the Hybridauth .

Comment: hybridauth is in vendor folder and the autoload file contains the following code:  `<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit9da23362304113093d59b5cbcc0e2b35::getLoader();
`

Comment: the  `autoload.json` , not `autoload.php`, and you should  give me the full path of hybridauth .

Comment: And the autoload filename is autoload.php It is  inside vendor folder

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: The code given does not match the error messages, Your error states that the class `triple Hybridauth` could not be found - however you pretend to not use a namespace, and address the class only with two `Hybridauth`. This is impossible with the PHP code. I also noted that you must have omitted the class where that `public function test_auth()` is a part of. Please: If you give code, always give the full code that does not work, or prepare a minimal nonworking example (that is preferred), and verify it does not work. Don't leave out code you think is irrelevant - it is the key for help here.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `new \Hybridauth\Hybridauth($config);` with a leading `\\` ?

Answer (score 0):

This file already included in codeigniter core file. dont need to incluse again in your class file

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Within your function

```
public function test_auth() {
  // Before code
    $config = [
        'callback' => 'https://example.com/path/to/script.php',
        'keys' => [ 'key' => 'your-twitter-consumer-key', 'secret' => 'your-twitter-consumer-secret' ]
    ];

    try {
        $twitter = new Hybridauth\Provider\Twitter($config);

        $twitter->authenticate();

        $accessToken = $twitter->getAccessToken();
        $userProfile = $twitter->getUserProfile();
        $apiResponse = $twitter->apiRequest( 'statuses/home_timeline.json' );
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'Oops, we ran into an issue! ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

        }
```

Check the usage from the package README

https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth

Comment: Tried every possible way. The problem is not with the hybridauth but composer itself. It is unable to locate classes inside my vendor folder. Thats the autoload issue most likely

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. When I install a package using the composer on the root location then it was still saying that the third party class not found. 
So here is my solution.
First of all, I change the "composer_autoload" config to TRUE.

> $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;

By default after change the above configuration Codeigniter looking vendor/autoload file under APPPATH(application folder) which is incorrect. So I change the constant to FCPATH(root path) because the root is the correct path to install the third-party packages using the composer.

change from 
**System/core/Codeigniter.php:165**

```
if ($composer_autoload === TRUE)
{
    file_exists(APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php')
        ? require_once(APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php')
        : log_message('error', '$config[\'composer_autoload\'] is set to TRUE but '.APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php was not found.');
}
```

to

```
if ($composer_autoload === TRUE)
{
    file_exists(FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php')
        ? require_once(FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php')
        : log_message('error', '$config[\'composer_autoload\'] is set to TRUE but '.FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php was not found.');
}
```

and finally, run

> composer dumpautoload

in case if still not working.
Happy coding!!!